# Make a PSobject showing published modules and their download count by author

Tags: powershell

While I did write something that managed to work
99% of the time someone knows how to do it better than me

I am just looking to learn how to improve my code

```
$mymods = @()

Find-Module | Where-Object { $_.Author -eq 'NAME' } | %{$mymods += ($_).name}

$dlCount = @()

$mymods | %{((find-module $_).additionalmetadata).downloadCount} | %{$dlCount += $_}

[int]$max = $mymods.count

if ([int]$dlCount.count -gt [int]$mymods.count) {$max = $dlCount.Count}

$results = for( $i = 0; $i -lt $max; $i++)
{
Write-Verbose "$($mymods),$($dlCount)"
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Modules = $mymods[$i]
        Count = $dlCount[$i]
}
}
$results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
Find-Module | ? Author -match "someone" | 
Select Name,Author,@{N="DownloadCount";E={$_.AdditionalMetadata.downloadCount}}
```

or:

```
$Modules | Group Author,{$_.AdditionalMetadata.downloadCount}
```

or:

- I suggest you to first save the results of `Find-Module` To a variable and use it each time instead of loading it every request, will perform faster

  `$Modules = Find-Module`

Comment: just woke up and tested this 
i may not have specified my intentions good enough 
the idea was to do it via a specific author 
ex: find all MY modules list them and the download count

Comment: So just update this: `Find-Module | ?  Author -match "someone"` and continue the code